# Geometric Figures Inside Java

Tags: java, windows, forms, object, ascii

Ok so I'm trying to draw a geometric figure for an assignment and I'm 95% done. My only problem is that, no matter how much I've tried to "smoothen" it, I still get something that doesn't work. (I've tried add .5). The figure I'm trying to recreate is elliptic.
The main method uses four integers : x=14 , y=8 , radiusA=5 , radiusB=1

Here is what the output should look like.

[image: Required output]

```
public static void DrawingFigures(int x, int y, int radiusA, int radiusB) {
  for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= 20; j++) {
      double dx = Math.pow(((j - x) / radiusA), 2);
      double dy = Math.pow(((i - y) / radiusB), 2);
      if (dx + dy == 1 && dx + dy == 1) {
        System.out.print("#");
      } else {
        System.out.print(" ");
      }
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

Now THIS is what I get from the previous method that I have shown previously.

[image: My output.]

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure to understand your question? The nested for loop is the one scanning my x's and y's positions. The formula inside the if statement is what determines where I want the "#"s to be.

Comment: Oh, well I wrote it down in the question but here it is : x=14 , y=8 , radiusA=5 , radiusB=1

Answer (score 0):

You're doing integer division in the middle of that.  Try casting `(j-x)` and `(i-y)` to `double` before each division, otherwise the result of each division will be rounded to the integer below.

Comment: I tried that, and I get the same result. Thanks for the try though.

Comment: Well, even if there's another bug as well, you'll need to do this anyway.  It won't work at all without the cast.

Answer (score 0):

The two issues you have are:

- you should use double instead of int as David mention above
- the resolution you are using with your formula is two small to see the ellipsis

Try to use x=27, y=7, radiusA=25, radiusB=5 and see the result. Changing to double will improve the precision.

Here is a modified version of your code using the above values (run using `java Test 25 5`):

```
public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] arg) {
    Test.DrawingFigures(Double.parseDouble(arg[0]), Double.parseDouble(arg[1]));
  }

  public static void DrawingFigures(double radiusA,
          double radiusB) {
    DrawingFigures(radiusA, radiusB, radiusA, radiusB);
  }

  public static void DrawingFigures(double x, double y, double radiusA,
          double radiusB) {
    for (double i = 0; i <= 2 * radiusB; i++) {
      for (double j = 0; j <= 2 * radiusA; j++) {
        if (Math.pow(((j - x) / radiusA), 2) + Math.pow(
                ((i - y) / radiusB), 2) == 1.0d) {
          System.out.print("#");
        } else {
          System.out.print(" ");
        }
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

Note in the code I use the radius values to compute x and y so it scales better instead of hard-coded `i<=20`, `j<=20`

Comment: I tried the program and it went out of bounds. But the thing is, part of the assignment requires me to hard code the values.